# Using city fixed effects control for variable

Tags: regression, confounding, partial-correlation

Some paper control for the term in regress function using city fixed effects(or the polynomials in the latitude and longitude of the city). I want to know the reason.

$lnY_i = \alpha + \beta ln A_i + \gamma ln K_i$

where $Y_i$ is GDP, $A_i$ is productivity, $K_i$ is capital. And we are interested in the relation of $K_i$ and $Y_i$, so we using city fixed effects(or latitude and longitude)to control for $A_i$

or if it is a panel data, it may use city fixed effects (year-interacted city dummy ) for the proxy variable of $A_i$.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise in your question. Maybe provide the formula of the regression so I can see the factors you're talking about

Comment: you still might need to be a bit clearer, like define how exactly you mean city fixed effects are controlling for $A_i$, before glen_b sees this post and locks it

Comment: using a city dummy for the proxy variable, how this can control for other variable

Comment: such like this paper Donaldson 2016 RAILROADS AND AMERICAN ECONOMIC GROWTH: A ‘‘MARKET ACCESS’’ APPROACH (footnote 50)